# Spacing between cols of table HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working on my website, http://www.isaveplus.com and I am having an issue of the table adding some space between each col (td) in it. My goal is to have the columns touching because I want the background color to blend in with each other. The picture below will show you what I meant by the space between them.

Thanks in advance!

```
 <table style="width:inherit; margin-left:-5px; margin-top:-5px; " cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
     <td class="searchBar" align="left" >
        <div id="ddtopmenubar" class="mattblackmenu" >
          <ul>
             <li><a  style="vertical-align:bottom;">Best of Coupons</a></li>
             <li>
                <a style="vertical-align:bottom;"> Best of Travel</a>
                <a style="vertical-align:bottom;">Grocery  stores</a>
             </li>
             <li><a style="vertical-align:bottom;">Office Supplies</a></li>
             <li><a style="vertical-align:bottom;"> Department <br /> stores </a></li>
             <li><a style="vertical-align:bottom;">Drug <br /> stores</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="searchBar" align="left">
           <asp:Button ID="whatIsIsavePlusButton" runat="server" onclick="whatIsIsavePlusButton_Click" style="color: #800000; font-weight: 700"     Text="?" Visible="False" />
      </td>
      <td class="searchBar" align="left">social media right here!</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

And the css for searchbar is:

```
 .searchBar
     {
       background-color: #414141;
       color:White;
       width:auto; 
       margin:-5px;

       padding:0px;  

     }
```

[image]

Comment: Tables should only be used for expressing tabular data, not for layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your links

```
<a style="vertical-align:bottom;">Best of Travel<a style="vertical-align:bottom;">Grocery  stores</a>
```

have a

```
border-right: 1px solid white
```

defined in

```
.mattblackmenu li a
```

there you can set the width of these white spaces

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't displaying the same in my browser as in the picture you give. But essentially I think you either want to put a negative `margin-right` on the div ddtopmenubar or a `border-left:1px solid white` on the following td. There might be another way to do it but I think that'd work.

Comment: It is a 1 vertical pixel spacing

Comment: Oh, are you talking about the nav bar? I assumed you were talking about towards the middle of the page. If you want to change the spacing in the navbar then just get rid of the line "border-right: 0px solid white;" in the class ".mattblackmenu li a" in the file "http://www.isaveplus.com/javascript/ddlevelsfiles/ddlevelsmenu-topbar.css"

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the `border-collapse` property?  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_border-collapse

`border-collapse: collapse;`